# How to calculate the number of characters on a line in Vimscript?

Tags: macvim, vim

I need an attribute or function in Vimscript that does a certain task if the current line contains a certain number of characters. For instance:

```
if ‹chars_on_current_line› = 50  " for example
    ... perform task ...
endif
```

What can I use for the `‹chars_on_current_line›` subexpression in Vimscript to get the length of the cursor line in characters?

(If it happens to help in any way, I'm using Macvim.)

Comment: tab being one character or ...?

Comment: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Count-characters-td1160474.html - help anything?

Comment: @Idigas Yes, that's the plan.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of characters on the current line, use

```
virtcol('$')
```

For the number of bytes, use

```
col('$')
```